# Type inheritance in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have some tables in SQL Server and a set of views and functions that add some extra columns to those tables. C# Linq-to-SQL wizard simply create all the types for me and I can use them.

My problem is: 
Added information are very small and I want the type of returned objects from views and functions to be same as main table but auto generated type are different.

I simply derive a type (say `View1`) from the table type (say `Table1`) and write a code to invoke my function (or open my view) with derived type. However, it throws an exception of type `InvalidOperationException` and say something like *`... is this the root of inheritance?`*.

So I want to know is this possible in Linq-to-SQL and C#, and if yes how can I do??

The following example requires the references of:

- System.Data.Linq.Mapping
- System.Data.Linq
- System.ComponentModel
- System.Reflection

**Example**

```
// Something like this added to the designer of dbml.
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Servers")]
public partial class DBServer : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private System.Guid _ID;

    private string _ServerName;

    private string _ServerIPs;

    private string _Name;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnIDChanging(System.Guid value);
partial void OnIDChanged();
partial void OnServerNameChanging(string value);
partial void OnServerNameChanged();
partial void OnServerIPsChanging(string value);
partial void OnServerIPsChanged();
partial void OnNameChanging(string value);
partial void OnNameChanged();
#endregion

    public DBServer()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ID", DbType="UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public System.Guid ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ID != value))
            {
                this.OnIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ID");
                this.OnIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ServerName", DbType="NVarChar(128) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string ServerName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ServerName;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ServerName != value))
            {
                this.OnServerNameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ServerName = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ServerName");
                this.OnServerNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ServerIPs", DbType="NVarChar(255) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string ServerIPs
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ServerIPs;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ServerIPs != value))
            {
                this.OnServerIPsChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ServerIPs = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ServerIPs");
                this.OnServerIPsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Name", DbType="NVarChar(255)")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Name != value))
            {
                this.OnNameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Name = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Name");
                this.OnNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I add this to a separate file:

```
public class DBServerEx: DBServer {
    long? _AssignedPermissions;
    long _InheritedPermissions;
    long _ActivePermissions;

    [ColumnAttribute(Storage="_AssignedPermissions", DbType="BigInt")]
    public long? AssignedPermissions {
        get {
            return this._AssignedPermissions;
        }
        set {
            if((this._AssignedPermissions!=value)) {
                this._AssignedPermissions=value;
            }
        }
    }

    [ColumnAttribute(Storage="_InheritedPermissions", DbType="BigInt NOT NULL")]
    public long InheritedPermissions {
        get {
            return this._InheritedPermissions;
        }
        set {
            if((this._InheritedPermissions!=value)) {
                this._InheritedPermissions=value;
            }
        }
    }

    [ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ActivePermissions", DbType="BigInt NOT NULL")]
    public long ActivePermissions {
        get {
            return this._ActivePermissions;
        }
        set {
            if((this._ActivePermissions!=value)) {
                this._ActivePermissions=value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In that file I have: 
(Note that it's a partial class and `MyDataContext` inherits `DataContext`)

```
partial class MyDataContext {
    [FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.uf_SelectServerWithPermissions", IsComposable=true)]
    public IQueryable<DBServerEx> SelectServerWithPermissions([ParameterAttribute(Name="UID", DbType="BigInt")] long uID) {
        return this.CreateMethodCallQuery<DBServerEx>(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), uID);
    }
}
```

In another file :

```
MyDataContext Context;
```

Now, when I call

```
from s in Context.SelectServerWithPermissions(uID)
select s;
```

I get the `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: can you provide a code example, at the point you get the exception.

Comment: @NasmiSabeer I have added a sample

Comment: @KenKin I change that part

Comment: I'm reading it and my previous comment is removed.

Comment: LINQ to SQL is mostly about direct mapping to database tables and views. If you want your conceptual model to differ from your physical model, then you should be using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

From [Inheritance Support (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386919%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

`LINQ to SQL supports single-table mapping. In other words, a complete inheritance hierarchy is stored in a single database table.`

More links:

[How to: Map Inheritance Hierarchies (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399352%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[How to: Configure Inheritance by Using the O/R Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb384573%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Linq to SQL Inheritance](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/01/linq-to-sql-inheritance.aspx)

[LINQ to SQL Inheritance model in an ASP.Net application](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2010/12/18/linq-to-sql-inheritance-model.aspx)

Comment: I already looked at those pages, AFAIK they say something about data in one table with various structures. for example teacher and person in table human(as your example say). but my function create a new type as you see in my example it add multiple fields to original table. now how can I handle this?